# 1 Why did Mozart use "had" when talking about the present regularity? 2 How about "I didn't know you ARE home" in this scene?

Tags: tense

"Amadeus" around 01:17:56-01:18:24/03:00:25

> LEOPOLD: Is she not here?
>
> MOZART: No, **she had to help her mother**.
>   She's like that.
>   Her mother's a very sweet woman, you'll--
>   **I didn't know you were home.**
>   Stanzi, this is my father.
>   We'll wait. We'll wait.

[image]
[image]

1 Why did Mozart use "had" when talking about the present regularity? ("She's like that.")

2 Can I say "I didn't know you *are* home" in this scene? Compared with "I didn't know you were home", which one is better?

Comment: He is not talking about the present.  He is referring to the obligation that **caused** her to leave.

Comment: He could say *She **has** to help her mother* in which case he would be referring to the present obligation that explains her absence.

Answer (score 2):

> she had to help her mother

Because she said him (past) something like this: "I have to help my mother". Her mother needed help yesterday (or at another moment in the past)

> I didn't know you are home

sounds somehow unidiomatic. I didn't know (past) you are home (present) seems to indicate that I can see the future (past -> present) but my ultra senses failed me.

> I didn't know you were home

This sounds correct. I didn't know you were home (both past) indicates that I apologize for entering your room without knocking (present) because I didn't know (past) what I know just now.

Before entering the room, I assumed (past) that you weren't home (past).

Comment: Another question:  why did Mozart use "had" when talking about the present situation?

Comment: Because she said him (past) something like this: "I have to help my mother". Her mother needed help yesterday (or at another moment in the past)

Comment: She may have said to him "I have to help my mother" and **had** in that case it would be the backshift for reported speech, but that's merely a plausible inference. Since there's no "She said she had to..." this can simply be a reference to the obligation that caused her to leave.